# iOS In App premium account for service?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

I'm working on an app that is basically a client to a custom service. The custom service is accessible via an iOS app or Android app, and recognizes users by their email address.

My intent is that users can purchase a subscription to the service from any device. On each device, though, I want to use the native store. The only way to make it on an iOS device is to go through Apple's In App Purchase. This should be a renewable subscription but tied to a specific service account (email address) rather than a device or group of devices.

I assume I can do the In App Purchase on the device, and I'm going to have to track the subscription within our custom service.

What I'm not sure of is how to tie this to a single email address, so the user can't upgrade as many service accounts to Premium accounts as they want. (The user can't sign in to multiple service accounts, but I'm concerned about them uninstalling the app and restoring purchases to different service accounts.)

How do I do this? Netflix and others manage this, but I'm not sure how.